# Extending the app from the Jellybean version to the Kitkat for SMS abort broadcast

Tags: android

I have a SMS app in Android which is working fine in jellybean version. The functionality this app provides is it reads the sms from the database and displays it, can send SMS to a number using SMSManager, on receiving the SMS it intercepts the SMS using the broadcast receiver for the incoming messages and if the SMS is from a specific number then it abort the broadcast of the SMS, and if the SMS is from the other numbers then it hides the usual notification and creates the notification.

Now I want the app to work both for the kitkat and Jellybean version...

Please Help me how can I extend my app t o provide the current functionality for the kitkat version too.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you mean abort braodcast is not stopping SMS notfication from popping up?

Comment: hey @Techfist I want to consume the SMS in my default app and not allow other apps to get notified about the received SMS from the specific number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the functionality you want in KitKat, your app is going to have to be the default SMS app. The default app is responsible for writing incoming messages to the Provider, and creating the appropriate Notifications. It listens for the `SMS_DELIVER` broadcast, and it is the only one to receive it, after which it can decide on the necessary actions.

Aborting the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast is no longer possible, and would not affect the default app's behavior anyway. Any app with the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission will still receive the broadcast, but only the default app can write to the Provider.

Writing your app to be the default SMS app is no trivial task, as it is expected to take on several responsibilities in addition to the ones already mentioned. The following link details what is necessary for your app to be eligible to be default.

[Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1)

Comment: Hey Mike M. ... Thanks a lot for your reply.... So if I want message from the specific number should not be visible in any of the messaging app(including my app which is currently the default app)... Is it possible to implement this functionality ??

Comment: No. The `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast cannot be aborted, starting with KitKat. Any app listening for it can get it and retrieve the message from its Intent. Furthermore, only the default app gets the `SMS_DELIVER` broadcast, so there'd be no chance to stop it beforehand. There's really no way to hide SMS anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... My app is working fine in Kitkat version too.. I have observed that when my app is set as the default SMS app, no other app is able to get the SMS from the specific number which I am aborting from my default SMS app.... I am still not able to figure out why it is able to hide those messages

Comment: Sorry, I think I was emphasizing the wrong things in my last comment. SMS apps written for KitKat are usually looking for the `SMS_DELIVER`, and if they aren't the default SMS app, they usually don't revert to looking for `SMS_RECEIVED`. That cannot be aborted; it's just that, apparently, no other apps on your system are looking for it. So, yeah, if your app is the default, and every other app is "playing nice", then yours will probably be the only one to care about incoming messages. If you were to install an app that looks only for the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast, it would still get it.

Comment: So, like my answer says, if your app is default, it decides which messages to allow through the normal channels.

Answer (score 0):

RSH, as Mike M suggested above, aborting SMS Received broadcast is no longer possible, prior to Kitkat you could have registered your receiver with an arbitirary large number as priority and upon receiving would aborted the same. but when same being done in kitkat no longer result into desirable output.

However in an workaround, you can try this to bypass it.

"When sms is received , it would be inserted into SMS database, all you need to do is figure out the newly inserted SMS is from a particular  record and delete the same from database, and a keep a local copy for your app for display"

This wont be a fullproof solution, but i guess it might produce the output you are looking at, just try implementing the same.

Comment: In KitKat, the default SMS app is the only app with write access to the Provider, and is responsible for writing the messages to it. If your app is the default, just don't write the messages. If it isn't the default, it won't be able to delete them.